# How to split the reports in a single dataset to Multiple Datasets uisng JCL

Tags: sorting, jcl

A dataset has many reports in it. I need the first report alone to another dataset. How can we achieve using JCL?

Below is the sample how the dataset looks like. My requirement is to sort out only the records under R0A report.

```
---Report - R0A---
List of Payments
Date : 23/07/2021
Name Payment-Amt Due-Date
AAAA  233.04     15/08/2021
BBBB   38.07     16/08/2021
---Report - R0B---
List of Payments
Date : 23/07/2021
Name Payment-Amt Due-Date
AAAA  233.04     15/08/2021
BBBB   38.07     16/08/2021
---Report - R0C---
List of Payments
Date : 23/07/2021
Name Payment-Amt Due-Date
AAAA  233.04     15/08/2021
BBBB   38.07     16/08/2021
```

Comment: Please edit your question and reformat the sample data as `code` so that line breaks are kept.

Comment: Please remove the JCL tag. You can't achieve any data manipulation via JCL; you always need at tool auch as a sort program. You will need JCL to run that tool as batch job, but that does not make this question a JCL question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the size of the reports is fixed, you can use sort with the `COPY` and `STOPAFT=` options:

```
SORT FIELDS=COPY,STOPAFT=6
```

If you need a report beyond the first, you can add the `SKIPREC=` option. E.g. to get the third report, specify:

```
SORT FIELDS=COPY,SKIPREC=12,STOPAFT=6
```

If the reports differ in length, you could run a simple REXX.

```
/* REXX - NOTE This is only a skeleton. Error checking must be added.     */
/*             This code has not been tested, so thorough testing is due. */

"ALLOC F(INP) DS('your.fully.qualed.input.data.set.name') SHR"
"EXECIO * DISKR INP ( STEM InpRec. FINISH"
"FREE F(INP)"

TRUE  = 1
FALSE = 0

ReportStartIndicator = "---Report"
ReportName           = "- R0B---"
ReportHeader         = ReportStartIndicator ReportName
ReportCopy           = FALSE

do ii = 1 to InpRec.0 while ReportCopy = FALSE
  if InpRec.ii = ReportHeader
  then ReportCopy = TRUE
  end

if ReportCopy 
then do
  OutRec.1 = InpRec.ii
  Outcnt   = 1

  do jj = ii + 1 to InpRec.0 while ReportCopy = TRUE
    if word( InpRec.jj, 1 ) = ReportStartIndicator /* Start of next report? */
    then ReportCopy = FALSE
    else do
      OutCnt        = OutCnt + 1
      OutRec.Outcnt = InpRec.jj
      end
    end

  "ALLOC F(OUT) DS('your.fully.qualed.output.data.set.name')" ,
      "NEW CATLG SPACE(......) RECFM(....) LRECL(....)"
  "EXECIO" OutCnt "DISKW OUT ( STEM OutRec. FINIS"
  "FREE F(OUT)"

  say "Done copying report." OutCnt "records have been copied."
  end
else do
  say "Report" ReportName "not found."
  exit 16
  end
```

As written in the comment in the REXX, I haven't tested this code. Also, error checking need to be added, especially for TSO HOST commands (ALLOC, EXECIO, FREE).

All of the solutions copy a *single* report to another data set. In the title, you wrote *to multiple datasets*. I'm sure you'll find solutions for this using above *single report* solutions.